# ios how to determine Family Sharing group purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

The user buys the goods through in app purchase. Can we determine whether the order is purchased by Family Sharing group Purchase? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In-app purchases are not shared via Family Sharing - See the [Note under the “types of in-app Purchase” table](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202023)

> In-app purchases aren't shared with family members in Family Sharing.